# Request fails with jquery-ajax but succeeded with curl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to initiate an ajax request.
When calling the request with jQuery I get an "Unexpected end of input" error and no response from the PHP file, but if I copy the request from the Chrome console as curl and run it with, say, linux command-line I get the correct response.

This is the ajax function:

```
        var form = $('#edit form').first();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php?uuid=' + uuid,
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }

        });
```

I've checked to see if maybe it's a Chrome issue, but it seems to happen in other browsers as well.

Thanks ahead

Comment: In your upload.php file how are you returning the data ? On a side note you are using POST why not pass uuid along with the post params ?

Comment: what is the dataType of the returned result.....is it json?

Comment: @iJay it is json. iv'e tried adding `        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',` like you've suggested in your answer but it didn't help

Comment: @PatsyIssa the upload.php file is also responding to different calls which are only using GET and the parameter sent to them is the same UUID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was with the form.serialize(). it turned it into a string and somehow didn't proccess it as a POST request. i had to make 'data' an object that gets each form input's value and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `contentType` and also if your `dataType` is json include that too
try this

```
var form = $('#edit form').first();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php?uuid=' + uuid,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
```

Comment: I dont think it will hurt it so badly